# What would be the R equivalent for this curl request

Tags: r, curl, rcurl, httr

I have a request in `curl` like this

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json"             \
     -X GET 127.0.0.1:8084/clusterpredict/byheaders \
     -v                                             \
     -b "text1"                                     \
     -A "text2"
```

How can I perform the same operation in `RCurl` or `httr` library in R?

Comment: I don't think `-b "text1"` is valid in the first place? Are you trying to post data or a cookie? Note that GET usually cannot be combined with data posting. Please clarify your example.

Comment: @Jeroen it'll try to read from that named cookie jar file if there is no `key=value` in the string. _"If  no '=' symbol is used in the line, it is treated as a filename to use to read previously stored cookie lines from, which should be used in this session if they match."_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `httr`:

- `-A` / `--user-agent` translates to `user_agent()`
- `-b` / `--cookie` translates to `set_cookies()` but you'll need to read in the cookie file and set them in the call to it (`RCurl` has constructs to read stored cookie files). I'm making this assumption since you didn't use the `"COOKIE1=1; COOKIE2=b"` format after `-b`. You can set them individually in `set_cookies()` as well
- `-H` / `--header` translates to `add_headers()` but there are special functions for setting content type (see below)
- `-v` / `--verbose` translates to `verbose()`
- `-X` / `--request` translates to the actual `VERB` functions (in this case `GET()`)

Here's one way to read cookies into a file for use in `set_cookie()` (if you are, indeed, using a cookie jar):

```
ctmp <- read.table("cookies.txt", sep="\t", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[,6:7]
crumbs <- setNames(as.character(as.character(ctmp$V6)), ctmp$V7)
```

So, your example would translate to `httr` as:

```
GET("http://127.0.0.1:8084/clusterpredict/byheaders", 
    content_type_json(),
    user_agent("text2"),
    set_cookies(.cookies=crumbs),
    verbose())
```

If you have individual cookies vs a cookie jar:

```
GET("http://127.0.0.1:8084/clusterpredict/byheaders", 
    content_type_json(),
    user_agent("text2"),
    set_cookies(COOKIE1="value1", COOKIE2="value2),
    verbose())
```

NOTE that `httr` will persist cookies between calls to the same domain in the same R session, so no need to keep specifying that file or those explicit cookie values in subsequent calls.

You can assign the value of the output to a variable then retrieve the content from it:

```
response <- GET("http://127.0.0.1:8084/clusterpredict/byheaders", 
    content_type_json(),
    user_agent("text2"),
    set_cookies(COOKIE1="value1", COOKIE2="value2),
    verbose())

result <- content(response)
print(str(result))
```

Generally, one would use the `jsonlite` package or `xml2` package (depending on the result type) to do the parsing vs rely on the built-in `httr` parsing since you can control the output better. In this case, it's JSON, so:

```
library(jsonlite)
result <- fromJSON(content(response, as="text"))
print(str(result))
```

Comment: Thanks it works :) is there any way to obtain a result of this question?

Comment: do you think you could help with this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513580/what-would-be-the-r-equivalent-for-such-curl-request

Answer (score 1):

Without a live address, this is hard to test, but here is something to get you started with `httr`.

```
library(httr)

#curl    -H "Content-Type:application/json"      -X GET  127.0.0.1:8084/clusterpredict/byheaders    -v -b "text1" -A "text2"
GET(
  "127.0.0.1:8084/clusterpredict/byheaders",
  add_headers(
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
  ),
  set_cookies("text1"),
  user_agent("text2"),
  verbose() #-v
)
```

Comment: cuz my expanded `httr` example was bad, eh? ;-)

Comment: @hrbrmstr we must have been answering at the same time.  of course, yours is much better and far more detailed.

Comment: i was just pokin' :-)